# Eventos no JavaScript

Tags: javascript, javascript-eventos

Estou estudando js e me deparei com o seguinte:

```
const h1 = document.querySelector('h1');

  //1
  h1.addEventListener('click', () => {
    alert('Funcionou!');
  });

  //2
  h1.onclick = () => {
    alert('Funcionou!');
  };
```

qual a diferença nas duas abordagens acima?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A principal diferença é que com o **onclick()** vc consegue associar apenas uma função como callback do evento. Já com o **addEventListener()** vc pode utilizar quantas funções quiser que todas elas serão ativadas quando o evento ocorrer.

Ambos estão corretos, mas nenhum deles é "melhor" por si só, e pode haver um motivo para o desenvolvedor escolher usar as duas abordagens.

**Exemplo** com o **onclick** (Só será executada a segunda função):

```js
let element = document.querySelector("#botao");

element.onclick = function() {
  alert("Primeira função");
}
element.onclick = function() {
  alert("Segunda função");
}
```

```html
<button id="botao">Aperte</button>
```

**Exemplo** com o **addEventListenner** (Serão executadas a primeira e segunda função):

```js
let element = document.querySelector("#botao");

element.addEventListener("click", function() {
  alert("Primeira função");
});

element.addEventListener("click", function() {
  alert("Segunda função");
});
```

```html
<button id="botao">Apertar</button>
```

**OBS:** O addEventListener() não funciona em versões anteriores ao Internet Explorer 9. Já o onclick() funciona em versões anteriores.

**Referências:** 
- [Alura](https://cursos.alura.com.br/forum/topico-diferenca-entre-addeventlistener-e-onclick-107006)
- [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348494/addeventlistener-vs-onclick)

- Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Não entendi o negativo. A explicação está correta.

Comment: Eu também não entendi. Mas estou aprendendo a respeitar e aceitar a opção de votos das pessoas. Por isso que eu entro na questão de ter que justificar o upvote e o downvote. Mas enfim, essa história já rendeu.

Comment: Pow, vlw pela resposta, explicação que estava precisando. Ajudou muito.

Comment: Show de bola, Paulo. Que a força esteja com vc!

Comment: @Gambi esse assunto so dá treta. Provavelmente é um hater seu. Imagina se ele negativa e deixa como resposta "Negativei porque não vou com a sua cara." 

Comment: Devo estar despertando amor em alguém por aqui e não sei. Rs

Comment: ... porém o mais importante foi ter ajudado o rapazinho ali. Isso já me é o suficiente.

Answer (score -2):

Também sou estudante de Js e não tenho tanto embasamento para falar, porém acredito que ambas fazem a mesma coisa só que usando recursos diferentes:
//1 usou um listener da lib e na //2 usou o DOM para ouvir o evento de clique.

Comment: Sua resposta tem mais valor se você pesquisar e adicionar referências. Quando a base é o *achismo*, passa a ser mais uma opinião do que uma resposta. Não digo que você está errado, mas sim que sua resposta pode ficar melhor.

Comment: Creio que eu tenha feito uma introdução mencionando isso amigo, obrigado.

Comment: Esse espaço é exclusivo para respostas. Quando tiver [pontos de reputação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) suficiente vai poder deixar comentários em perguntas e respostas. Até lá use esse campo apenas para respostas que solucionem ao problema proposto.